# What is the probability that exactly two of them are trout if we know that at least three of them are not?

Tags: probability

In a small lake, it is estimated that there are 105 fish, of which 40 are trout and 65 are of another species. A fisherman catches 8 fish. What is the probability that exactly two of them are trout if we know that at least three of them are not?

**My work**

Let $E_1=$"Exactly two trout"
$E_2$="At least three of them are not trout."
$A_1$="2 trout"
$A_2$="exactly 3 are not trout" 
$B_1$="2 trout"
$B_2$="exactly 4 are not trout
$C_1$="2 trout"
$C_2$="exactly 5 are not trout
$D_1$="2 trout"
$D_2$="exactly 6 are not trout

We know

$P(E_1|E_2)=P(A_1|A_2)+P(B_1|B_2)+P(C_1|C_2)+P(D_1|D_2)$

Solving $P(A_1|A_2)=\frac{P(A_1\cap A_2)}{P(A_2)}=\frac{\frac{2}{40}\times\frac{3}{65}}{\frac{3}{105}}=\frac{21}{260}$

Analogous for the other cases.

Then $P(E_1|E_2)=\frac{84}{260}=0.32$

Is good the reasoning?

Note: This exercise only can solved using conditional probability.

Comment: It may be easier to change your question to number of trout caught.  What is the probability that exactly two are trout given at most 5 are trout.  Notice that exactly 2 AND at most 5 is exactly 2.

Comment: But give the same result? @MaggieMyers

Comment: I'm not sure you are doing right conditional probability.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, Am I getting different result?

Events:

$A...$ exactly 2 of them are trouts

$B...$ at least 3 are not

$$P(A|B) = {P(A\cap B)\over P(B)} = {{40\choose 2}\cdot {65\choose 6}\over {105\choose 8}-{40\choose 8}\cdot {65\choose 0}-{40\choose 7}\cdot {65\choose 1}-{40\choose 6}\cdot {65\choose 2} } =..$$

Comment: I think you have a negative result...

Comment: I made an edit.......

Comment: To find the probability of A and B, which is P(A) since A is a subset of B,you look for the probability that two are trout and 6 aren't which is C(40,2)*C(65,6)/C(105,8).  So your denominator is fine but the 8 in the numerator should be a 6, right?

Comment: Yeah, you are right. :)

Answer (score 0):

Adding conditional probability doesn't work like that. If it did, you could end up with probability greater than one. For instance, what's the probability of a card being something other than an ace? P(not ace|clubs) = P(not ace|diamonds) = P(not ace|clubs) = P(not ace|clubs) = 12/13. So is p(not ace) = 48/13?

You need to add up all the possible ways of getting both E$_1$ and E$_2$, and divide by the total number of ways of getting E$_2$. Dividing the subcases and then adding gets a different answer than adding, *then* dividing.